# Is code analyzer supported in ros_buildfarm?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am interested in the "Make ROS package quality visible" work by the Quality Assurance WG.
Is it currently supported to execute code analysis on the ros_buildfarm?

I found some scripts for code analyzer which are noted "deprecated" in the ros-infrastructure repository.
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/tree/master/code_quality

Then I have checked the wiki page of code_quality and the scripts directory in ros_buildfarm but couldn't find the answer.
http://wiki.ros.org/code_quality
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/tree/master/scripts

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329338/is-code-analyzer-supported-in-ros_buildfarm?/) by [akihikotsukuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/37563/akihikotsukuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general we don't add code analyzers / linters to the buildfarm alone since it would make it difficult to reproduce the results locally.

Instead in ROS 2 any kind of linters are integrated on a per-package level. So when you run the tests of a package you also run any kind of linter available (e.g. `clang-format`, `clang-tidy`, `cppcheck`, `cpplint`, `flake8`, `uncrustify`, `xmllint`). The generally used ones are in this repo: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint All of these produce xUnit compliant result file to be picked up by Jenkins when running the tests in the buildfarm.

For ROS 1 there is no such infrastructure for linters and you would need to integrate each linter manually into each package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akihikotsukuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/37563/akihikotsukuda/) on 2019-07-28**:
I understood the current policy for ROS 1 infrastructure. Thank you!